# JPA Query from 3 column join table

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a following Entities. Means that User can belong to many businesses and for each business this user can has separate permissions. So an existing user can be assigned to another business. The Business_User table looks like this:

```
USER_ID  BUSINESS_ID    AUTHORITY_NAME  
6         1             ROLE_ANALYTICS
6         1             ROLE_SELF_ANALYTICS
7         1             ROLE_REVIEWS
8         1             ROLE_ANALYTICS
8         1             ROLE_SELF_ANALYTICS
8         1             ROLE_REVIEWS
6         2             ROLE_REVIEWS
6         2             ROLE_SELF_ANALYTICS
```

**Question:** I am querying Users for ONE business by trying to build list of user DTO objects, that DTO exposes `List<Authority>`, problem is that I can't figure how should I get these authorities for each user from the Business_User table. Been trying to do fancy stuff with lambdas but have no luck. I am using Spring Data for queries, maybe can solve it in the repository.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: If I would go another route by adding new join table `BUSINESS_USER_AUTHORITY`, how would I have to describe it in `UserBusiness` class? I also would like the primary key to be over user_id and business_id. Note that `name` is PK in `Authority` table.

Something like this, but that does not create me join table at all.

Change **UserBusiness** class:

```
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(
      name = "BUSINESS_USER_AUTHORITY",
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "business_user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "authority_name", referencedColumnName = "name")})
  private Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
```

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  })
  private Set<BusinessUser> businessUsers = new HashSet<>();
}
```

**BusinessUser**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BUSINESS_USER")
@IdClass(BusinessUser.class)
public class BusinessUser implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  private User user;

  @Id
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "business_id")
  private Business business;

  @Id
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "authority_name")
  private Authority authority;

}
```

**Business**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BUSINESS")
public class Business implements Serializable {

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "business_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
  })
  private Set<BusinessUser> businessUsers = new HashSet<>();

}
```

**Authority**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AUTHORITY")
public class Authority implements Serializable {

  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 0, max = 50)
  @Id
  @Column(length = 50)
  private String name;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to drop the whole `BusinessUser` entity, and instead link `Authority` to a `Business`? That's the way it goes logically anyways, and your `BusinessUser` is just a synthetic construct in between.

Comment: I don't see a solution here. How would I know what authorities one user has in that business. I just thought of adding another table business_user_ authority and in business_user I would have a FK on that table. Then I have List<Authority> in BusinessUser table and I can query BusinessUsers and map the authorities from there. Maybe unnecessary?

Comment: Ah, I guess your `Authority` entity is shared by users instead of being just a simple role String. Then you do need the join table. A JPQL query with a `SELECT DISTINCT User ...` would get you all the users for a business.

Comment: So, where is the code you tried? Also, your mapping is wrong. The OneToMany shouldn't have a JoinColumn, and should be `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")`.

Comment: Nothing gets saved into the Business_User table without the JoinColumn. There's nothing certain I came up with, just asking for better approach maybe. Probably will go with another join table.

Comment: From the perspective of ease of coding, adding another association table seems sensible.  I would also suggest to have artificial primary key (`id`) columns for the association tables as well.  That way, the relationship between the two association tables will also become easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a function like that, but if anyone has a solution how would the design look with another join table between BusinessUser <--> BusinessUserAuthority then I'd be glad to implement it.

```
  private Function<Map.Entry<User, List<BusinessUser>>, UserManagementDTO> getPermissionForUser() {
    return user -> {
      UserManagementDTO dto = userManagementMapper.userToUserManagementDTO(user.getKey());
      dto.setAuthorities(user.getValue().stream().map(BusinessUser::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
      return dto;
    };
  }
```